# Makefile to compile c/h?

Tags: c, makefile, compilation

I need to compile an old application whose tarball only contains *.c and *h, ie. no Makefile. The root directory contains the application, and a sub-directory contains a library the application needs.

My make/Makefile knowledge isn't great, and I was wondering what the easiest way would be to compile this application + library.

Thank you.

---

Edit: Using this script...

```
# cat compile.bash
#!/bin/bash

cd mylib
for cfile in *.c; do
   ofile=$(echo "$cfile" | sed 's#.c$#.so#')
   gcc -shared -c "$cfile" -o "$ofile"
done

cd ..
gcc *.c -I mylib -L mylib -mylib -o myapp
```

... I notice that each *.c file in mylib/ is compiled into a *.so file instead of compiling each into an object file and building a single .so file, and I get tons of warnings and errors, eg.

```
unzip.c: In function âunzipâ:
unzip.c:991: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments

gcc: unrecognized option '-mylib'

file_util.c: In function âfile_moveâ:
file_util.c:98: error: âerrnoâ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

I don't know how to compile the library, and then compile the application without error/warning.

Comment: Ouch - an invocation of sed for every source file?? If you really need to set that variable, try `ofile=${cfile%.c}.so` which should do about the same thing without starting another process for every source file each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use a for loop or generate intermediate object files:

```
 (cd mylib && gcc -shared -fPIC -o libfoo.so *.c) && \
   gcc -Imylib -o app *.c mylib/libfoo.so
```

Comment: Thanks for the commands. I get bazillions of warnings/errors, so I assume that I'm either missing some pointers to headers/libs or some other switch (eg. ansi, std99, etc.) www.pastebin.com/brPvXhdz

Comment: Problem solved: I was using an older version of the toolchain than I should have used. Also, using just CFLAGS=-Wall -02 removes the warnings.

Answer (score 1):

Compile the library:

```
cd libfoo
for cfile in *.c; do
   ofile=$(echo "$cfile" | sed 's#.c$#.so#')
   gcc -shared -c "$cfile" -o "$ofile"
done
```

After this, you should have a `libfoo.so` file in libfoo/. Then, compile the program (Don't forget to `cd` back):

```
gcc *.c -I libfoo -L libfoo -lfoo -o application
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is probably to get an IDE to do the build for you.  Netbeans for one will create a Makefile so you can then build the project independently of the IDE.